# Extracting responses from API call

Tags: r, dplyr, httr

I have an API call that comes in one of three responses:

```
The first type of response:
   [[1]]
    Response [https://api.secure.com/v4/people/111548751]
      Date: 2022-09-07 01:28
      Status: 200
      Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
      Size: 2.16 kB
    {
      "Id": 111548751,
      "firstName": "Jeff",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "middleName": null,
      "suffix": null,
      "title": null,
      "sourceFileTitle": null,
      "sourceFileFirstName": null,
      "sourceFileMiddleName": null,
    ...
```

The second type of response:

```
[[1]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v4/people/findOrCreate/]
  Date: 2022-09-07 01:29
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 58 B
{
  "Id": 111634535,
  "status": "UnmatchedStored"
```

And finally, the third response:

```
[[1]]
Response [https://api.secure.com/v4/people/findOrCreate/]
  Date: 2022-09-07 05:38
  Status: 500
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 164 B
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
      "text": "An unknown error occurred",
      "referenceCode": "A-7731DC-490283"
    }
  ]
```

Right now, these responses are stored in a list response called `get_data`. I have some code sets up that extracts three pieces of data from all of these responses that looks like this:

```
data_log <- get_data %>% 
  map_df(extract, c("url", "date", "status_code"))
```

This will be a table that produces those three values from every response. But what I'm also trying to do is add the field `Id` from all of the responses that contain the value (like the first two ones). If it doesn't contain a value for `Id` (like the last response), the output would just say "No ID"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe `get_data %>% map_chr(~pluck(content(.), "Id", .default="No ID"))` will get your the ID column which you can bind to your data.frame.

Comment: @MrFlick What other information would you need me to provide? It's an API call, so I can't provide the exact specifics without giving away security credentials.

Comment: If there is no publicly available API that can be used for testing, then we can't really verify that any possible solution will for sure work. You could create a dummy plumber API in R that would replicate the behavior that you wish to test. At least that way testing would be possible.